# Vector3.MoveTowards() is not working with TouchInputs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying make a functionality to my game so that the object with **containerTransform** can move 720f left or right depending upon the touch inputs. I have used **Vector3.MoveTowards()** but, it shows a **glitchy back and forth movement whenever I swipe right or left, instead of proper transition 720f right or left. I am not sure where my logic went wrong. Here are the complete codes. I am seeking your help. Thank you

```
private Vector2 startPosition;
private Vector2 endPosition;

public Transform containerTransform;
public float speed;
public float SoftZone = 20f;
//soft zone is the distance upto which the swipe wont work, so swipe length less than it wont trigger the function;

private bool SwipeLeft;
private bool SwipeRight;
private bool boolean;

private Vector3 currentLocation;
private Vector3 endLocation;

void Start()
{
    currentLocation = containerTransform.position;
    endLocation = containerTransform.position;
}


void Update()
{

    if(SwipeLeft) {

        containerTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(

            currentLocation, 
            endLocation,
            Time.deltaTime * speed
            );

        if(containerTransform.position == endLocation) {

            SwipeLeft = false;
            currentLocation = endLocation;

            print("swipeleft ends");
        }
    }

    if(SwipeRight) {

        containerTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(

            currentLocation, 
            endLocation,
            Time.deltaTime * speed
            );

        if(containerTransform.position == endLocation) {

            SwipeRight = false;
            currentLocation = endLocation;

            print("swiperight ends");
        }
    }

    SwipeCheck ();
}

void SwipeCheck () {

    /*if (!SwipeConfirmed){*/

 foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            startPosition = touch.position;
            endPosition = touch.position;

            boolean = true;
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            endPosition = touch.position;
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended ||
            touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled &&
            boolean == true)
        {
            if (startPosition.x - endPosition.x >= SoftZone)
            {

                SwipeLeft = true;
                print("left");

                endLocation += new Vector3(

                    endLocation.x - 720f, 
                    endLocation.y, 
                    endLocation.z
                );

            }
            else if(startPosition.x - endPosition.x <= -SoftZone)
            {   

                SwipeRight = true;
                print("right");

                endLocation += new Vector3(

                    endLocation.x + 720f, 
                    endLocation.y, 
                    endLocation.z
                );
                boolean = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you having an issue with `MoveTowards` or with getting the `Vector3` from your swipe logic? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help here determining where your issue really is. I suggest code with debug statements showing your calculations and then copy-paste the output like code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [Touch.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html) gives you

> The position of the touch in **pixel coordinates.**

In order to use them for `transform.position`, you have to convert them to world space 3D coordinates using [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) like

```
var worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, distanceToCamera);
```

Where `distanceToCamera` is a value you have to define/calculate to determine how far the point should be in front of the camera.

---

Note

If you use this often as in `Update`, you should store the `Camera` and reuse the reference like this:

```
private Camera cam;

private void Awake ()
{
    cam = Camera.main;
}

//...

var worldPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint( ... );
```

---

**The main issue**

You are using

```
Vector3.MoveTowards(currentLocation, endLocation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

This will always start a new movement from `currentLocation` so you never move more than one step/frame away from the `currentLocation`.

Instead, use the actual current position of the object

```
containerTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(containerTransform.position, endPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

Your code, `SwipeLeft` and `SwipeRight` actually do the same thing, so you could just remove one of the blocks.

```
if (Swipe)
{
    containerTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(containerTransform.position, endPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (containerTransform.position == endLocation)
    {
        Swipe = false;
        currentLocation = endLocation;

        print("swipe ends");
    }
}
```

and only set `Swipe = true;`

---

However, I would recommend using [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) instead of doing stuff in `Update` since they are better to control using `StartCoroutine` and `StopCoroutine` and passing the value you in you don't need the local variables `currentLocation` and `endLocation`.

It could look like

```
// Makes sure only one scrolling process is running at a time
private bool isScrolling;

private IEnumerator MoveTo(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    if (isScrolling) yield break;

    isScrolling = true;
    while (containerTransform.position != targetPosition)
    {
        containerTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(containerTransform.position, endPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return null;
    }

    isScrolling = false;
    print("Swipe ends");
}
```

If you rather would like to swipe within a certain time regardless how far the distance is you could use `Vector3.Lerp` instead

```
public float swipeDuration;

private IEnumerator MoveTo(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    if (isScrolling) yield break;

    isScrolling = true;

    var currentPosition = containerTransform.position;

    var timePassed = 0.0f;

    while (timePassed < swipeDuration)
    {
        var lerpFactor = timePassed / swipeDuration;

        containerTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, endPosition, lerpFactor);

        yield return null;
    }

    // To be sure set a fixed end position
    containerTransform.position = endPosition;

    isScrolling = false;
    print("Swipe ends");
}
```

Adobt your code in `SwipeCheck()` to use the new coroutine.

```
StartCoroutine (MoveTo(endLocationWorldPoint));
```